# How to show modal and get the Data for Update

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi i want to ask about my problem, so in my case i want to show a modal from "Edit" button and then the modal get data from database based on id. This is my code and still didn't work. Can you tell me where i missing it?

tokoCrud.php

```
<?php
        include ('crudAction.php');

        function insertData($db, $tableName) {
            $data = [
                'id_ot' => ' ',
                'nama_ot' => $_POST['namaToko'],
                'alamat_ot' => $_POST['alamatToko'],
                'status_ot' => '1'
            ];

            if(!isDataTokoExist($db, $namaToko)) {
                session_start();
                include ('logger.php');
                $query = buildInsertQuery($tableName, $data);
                $idTarget = 'Master Barang';
                $data = ['username_pstr' => $_SESSION['username'], 'Create' => 'DataToko'];
                writeLogToko($db, $_SESSION['idpengguna'], $idTarget, 'Toko', 'Insert Data Toko', $data);
                return runQuery($db, $query, 'insert');
                
            }
            else {
                header('location: ' . $_REQUEST['pageReferrer'] . '&error=false&message=' . $result['message']);
                }
            }

        function updateData($db, $tableName) {
                $data = [
                    'id_ot' => ' ',
                    'nama_ot' => $_POST['namaToko'],
                    'alamat_ot' => $_POST['alamatToko']
                ];

                if(isset($_GET['idToko'])) {
                  $tokoId = $_GET['idToko'];
                  }
                $query = buildUpdateQuery($tableName, $data);
                $query .= " WHERE id_ot = '$tokoId' ";
                return runQuery($db, $query, 'update');
            }

        function isDataTokoExist($db, $namaToko) {
                $namaToko = $_POST['namaToko'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM master_toko WHERE nama_ot = '$namaToko'";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                return $result -> num_rows > 0;
            }
        
        function getDataToko() {
            $db = getDBConnection();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM master_toko ORDER BY id_ot DESC";
            $result= mysqli_query($db, $query);
            return $result;
        }

        function getDetailToko($db, $tableName) {
            $tokoId = $_GET['idToko'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id_ot = $tokoId";
            $result = runQuery($db, $query, 'select');

            return mysqli_fetch_array($result['data'], MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        }


        
    ?>
```

This is endpoint.php

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
$objectType = $_GET['objectType'];
$db = getDBConnection();

$tableName = getTableName($objectType);
$return = [];
if ($objectType === 'toko') {
    include 'tokoCrud.php';
  if ($action === 'get') {
    $return = getDetailToko($db, $tableName);
  }
}

return json_encode($return);
die();

?>
```

This is formAction.php

```
<?php
$actionObject = $_REQUEST['actionObject'] ?? '';
$actionType = $_REQUEST['actionType'] ?? '';

include $actionObject .'Crud.php';
include 'config.php';

function getTableName($actionObject) 
{
  $tableMapping = [
    'toko' => 'master_toko'
    // 'barang' => 'table_barang',
    // 'jenis' => 'table_jenis',
  ];
    return $tableMapping[$actionObject];
}

$db = getDBConnection();
$tableName = getTableName($actionObject);

switch($actionType):
  case 'insert' : $result = insertData($db, $tableName);
      break;
  case 'delete' : $result = deleteData($db, $tableName);
    break;
  case 'update' : $result = updateData($db, $tableName);
    break;
endswitch;

if (!$result['error']) {
  header('location: ' . $_REQUEST['pageReferrer'] . '&error=false&message=' . $result['message']);
} else {
    header('location: ' . $_REQUEST['pageReferrer'] . '&error=true&message=' . $result['message']);
}




?>
```

This is crudAction.php

```
<?php

function runQuery($db, $query, $queryType) {

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(!empty(mysqli_error($db))) {
        return [
            'error' => true,
            'message' => mysqli_error($db)
        ];
    }
        
        return [
            'error' => false,
            'message' => getMessage($queryType),
            'data' => $result
        ];
}

function buildInsertQuery($tableName, $data) {

    $tableColumns = [];
    $insertValues = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        array_push($tableColumns, $key);
        array_push($insertValues, $value);
    }

    $columns = "(`" . implode("`,`", $tableColumns) . "`)";
    $values = "('" . implode("','", $insertValues) . "')";
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` ". $columns . " VALUES " . $values ." ";
    
    return $query ?? false;
}

function buildUpdateQuery($tableName, $data) {
    $tableColumns = [];
    $insertValues = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        array_push($tableColumns, $key);
        array_push($insertValues, $value);
    }

    $columns = "(`" . implode("`,`", $tableColumns) . "`)";
    $values = "('" . implode("','", $insertValues) . "')";
    $query = "UPDATE `$tableName` SET ". $columns ." = " .$values ." ";
    
    return $query ?? false;
}


function getMessage($queryType) {
    $messages = [
        'insert' => 'Data has been succesfuly added',
        'update' => 'Data has been succesfuly updated',
        'delete' => 'Data has been succesfuly deleted',
        'select' => 'Data has been selected',
        'dataDouble' => 'Data Ada yang Dobel'
    ];  

    return $messages[$queryType];
}

function getLastID() {
    return mysqli_insert_id();
}
?>
```

This is master_toko.php

```
<?php
  require "partial/header.php";
  require "partial/sidebar.php";
  include ('library/services/tokoCrud.php');
  // include 'messageBox.php';
 ?>
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Master Toko</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Master Toko</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    <?php include 'library/services/messageBox.php'; 
                ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Data Toko</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modalBesar">Tambah Data</button>
              </div>
            <!-- Bagian Form Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade modalBesar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Toko</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form method = "post" action = "library/services/formAction.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageReferrer" value="http://localhost/city/?page=store" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionObject" value="toko" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="insert" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nama Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="namaToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Alamat Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamatToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="alamatToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Akhir Bagian Modal -->
            <!-- Bagian Edit Form Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade modalBesar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id = "modalUpdate">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Data Toko</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form method = "post" action = "library/services/formAction.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageReferrer" value="http://localhost/city/?page=store" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionObject" value="toko" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="update" >
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="get" >
                <input type="hidden" name="idToko" value="<? $idToko; ?>" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nama Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="namaToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Alamat Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamatToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="alamatToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Save</button>
              </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Akhir Edit Bagian Modal -->
            

              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Toko</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Opsi</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $n=1;
                    $toko = getDataToko();
                    while ($dataToko = mysqli_fetch_array($toko)) {
                      if($dataToko['status_ot']==1)
                      {
                        $status = "Aktif";
                        $idStatus = "1"; 
                      }
                      if($dataToko['status_ot']==2)
                      {
                        $status = "Tidak Aktif";
                        $idStatus = "2"; 
                      }
                    
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $n++; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $dataToko['nama_ot'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $dataToko['alamat_ot'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $status ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <button type = "button" class = "view-detail btn btn-success"> Edit </button>
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger deletebtn"> Delete </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>   
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  
  <?php require "partial/footer.php"; ?>
                  
  <script> 
  
  let buttonDetail = document.querySelectorAll('.view-detail');
  buttonDetail.forEach((function(_el))  {
    _el.addEventlistener('click', function(e) {
      var modal = _el.getAttribute("modalBesar");
      let idToko = e.target.dataset.id;
      $.ajax ({
          url: 'http://localhost/city/library/services/endpoint.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {action: 'get', objectType: 'toko', idToko: 'idToko'},
          dataType: 'json',
          success : function(response) {
            let namaToko = response.namaToko;
            let alamatToko = response.alamatToko;
          }
      });

    });
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Lots of code. "_This is my code and still didn't work_" _What_ doesn't work? Blank page? Modal not opening? Wrong data inserted into modal?

Comment: when I press the edit data button, it can't show up the modal and and can't retrieve data into the modal hehe

Comment: Where exactly are you triggering your modal? `var modal = _el.getAttribute("modalBesar");` Looks like your edit button doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: <button type = "button" class = "view-detail btn btn-success" modal=".modalBesarEdit"> Edit </button>

I have add "modal" for attribute in the "Edit" button for the triggering

Comment: That still isn't the attribute `modalBesar`. Supposing you're using Bootstrap4 you might want to read [the docu on modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

Comment: Ahh okey Thankyouu